# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "Moral" und "Ethik"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *Moral* und *Ethik*?
Bzw. wie unterscheidet sich *eine moralisch richtige* von *einer ethisch richtigen* Handlung?

Comment: So wie ich die Frage verstehe, gehört sie eher nach Philosophy.SE als hierher...

Comment: @Jan: Naja, es geht um die *Bedeutung* zweier Worte. Ich frage nicht ob eine bestimmte Handlung moralisch/ethisch richtig ist, sondern wo der Unterschied zwischen diesen Kategorien besteht.

Comment: See also [this](http://www.philosophyblog.com.au/ethics-vs-morality-the-distinction-between-ethics-and-morals/), [this](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-the-difference-between-ethics-and-morals.htm) and [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/ethics-versus-morals).

Comment: @bitmask Das ist aber keine Abgrenzung, die sich spezifisch in der deutschen Sprache findet, oder?

Comment: Solche Begriffe können schon sprachspezifisch unterschiedlich verwendet werden. "Kultur" wäre auch so ein schillernder Begriff.

Comment: @Jan - Genau. Ich spreche Niederländisch und habe mich das auch gefragt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In gehobeneren Diskussionen wird der Unterschied zwischen Moral und Ethik oft darin gesehen, dass Ethik auf gewissen Grundsätzen beruht, aus denen sich dann die weitere Ethik ableiten muss, während bei Moral die Grundlage der Bewertung nicht näher spezifiziert werden muss.

In diesem Sinne wäre es unmoralisch, sich in der Öffentlichkeit zu küssen, wenn die Begründung ist, dass das einfach ekelhaft ist. Würde hingegen ein ausgefeiltes Ethiksystem zugrunde gelegt, in dem ein ethischer Grundsatz ist, dass alle Handlungen eines Menschen unmittelbar für das Kollektiv nützlich sein müssen, dann kann man eine in dieser Hinsicht sinnlose Zeitverschwendung als unethisch bezeichnen. (Bitte dieses Beispiel nicht überbewerten, ich versuche nur, die unpräzisen Unterschiede etwas auszuarbeiten.)

Andererseits werden im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch Moral und Ethik weitgehend synonym gebraucht, sodass ein Verweis auf obige Bedeutungsunterschiede im normalen Gespräch meistens eine eristische Kampfmaßnahme ist.

Die Etymologie hilft nicht wirklich weiter, da Moral und Ethik von analogen Wörtern im Lateinischen und Griechischen kommen.

Comment: Wenn ich Dich richtig verstehe, dann ist Ethik also eine objektivere Form von Moral, da sie aus einer Menge von allgemeinen Grundsätzen logisch ableitbar ist, während Moral durch subjektive, *situationsbedingte*, Weltanschauung generiert wird?

Comment: @bitmask Einige moralische Grundsätze scheinen angeboren zu sein, das ist von subjektiv weit entfernt, sie sind nur nicht bewusst reflektiert. Ich hoffe, das Beispiel so gewählt zu haben, dass klar ist, dass eine Wertung durch die ethische Begründung nicht richtiger oder sympathischer wird. Der Vorteil der ethischen Begründung im obigen Sinn besteht darin, dass sie einen Ansatzpunkt für eine Diskussion bietet, die bei der Begründung mit Ekel fehlt. Da aber die beiden Wörter oft synonym verwendet werden, kann man aus der Verwendung von "Moral" i.a. nicht auf fehlende Begründung schließen.

Comment: Ich werte Absatz 3 und 4 auf, und halte 1 & 2 für weniger stark.

Comment: richtige Spur, ich würde sagen Ethik ist eine intersubjektives institutionalisiertes Destillat von einzelnen moralischen Empfinden einer grösseren Gruppe von Personsen und impliziert eine moralische "Einigung" (Ne, noch geschwollener kann ich es nicht ausdrücken ;)) Siehe auch Kommentar bei John

Answer (score 8):

Es gibt keine klare eindeutige Abgrenzung. Am ehesten kommt man damit hin zu sagen, daß Ethik eine (Sitten-)Lehre oder Philosophiedisziplin darstellt (z. B. Ethik als Schulfach, Berufsethik) und daß Moral das sittliche Empfinden einzelner darstellt. Sehr schwammig, ich weiß.

Hier die Gedanken der Leute, die meine Lieblingsreferenz erstellt haben:

> [Moral](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Moral)
>
> **1a.**  Gesamtheit von ethisch-sittlichen Normen, Grundsätzen, Werten, die das zwischenmenschliche Verhalten einer Gesellschaft regulieren, die von ihr als verbindlich akzeptiert werden
>     **1b**.   sittliches Empfinden, Verhalten eines Einzelnen, einer Gruppe; Sittlichkeit
>     **2.**    (Philosophie) (besonders bei Kant) Lehre vom sittlichen Verhalten des Menschen; Ethik
>     **3.**   Bereitschaft, sich einzusetzen; Disziplin, Zucht; gefestigte innere Haltung, Selbstvertrauen
>     **4.**    lehrreiche Nutzanwendung; Lehre, die aus etwas gezogen wird
>
> [Ethik](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ethik)
>
> **1a.**   philosophische Disziplin oder einzelne Lehre, die das sittliche Verhalten des Menschen zum Gegenstand hat; Sittenlehre, Moralphilosophie
>   **1b.**   die Ethik darstellendes Werk
>   **2.**    (bildungssprachlich) Gesamtheit sittlicher Normen und Maximen, die einer  [verantwortungsbewussten] Einstellung zugrunde liegen
>   **3.**   Ethik als Schulfach

Comment: ein mir einigermassen schlüssiges Kriterium scheint zu sein, ob wir von einer institutionalisierten Form von Moral sprechen: *Ethikkommission, Berufsethik*, wenn der Begriff also mehrere Personen/Stände und nicht die Moral des einzelnen repräsentiert (*Arbeitsmoral, Moralpredigt*), hier wird imo meist "moralisch" benutzt. "Ethik" eher bei festen Begriffen wie auch http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moral%2C+ethik%2C+moralisch%2C+ethisch&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3 suggeriert

Answer (score 2):

Der Unterschied zwischen Moral und Ethik:

**Moral**: Konkrete Verhaltensregeln, also quasi Vorschiften, die das Leben in einer Gesellschaft regeln.

**Ethik**: Nachdenken über und Bewerten der Moral. Die Ethik ist quasi die Wissenschaft, die entscheidet, ob und warum eine Handlung moralisch ist.

Comment: Servus und herzlich willkommen bei German.stackexchange.com! Leider ist deine Antwort nicht von sehr hoher Qualität. Ich würde dir raten, im [FAQ-Bereich (engl.)](http://german.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) die Hinweise zum Erstellen guter Antworten durchzulesen, und dann deine Antwort zu verbessern (mithilfe des edit-Links). Auf gute Zusammenarbeit! =)

Comment: Absolute Kleinschreibung ist auf einer Seite wie dieser, wo auch viele Lernende unterwegs sind, eine sehr schlechte Idee.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting topic which I don't think is any different whether we're talking about German or English. So I'm going to answer it from the English perspective:

An ethical breach must include an element of abuse of power or trust. It's unethical for a professor to "persuade" his student to have sex with him because of the power relationship. Even if she's a willing participant. It's unethical.

Immoral behavior should in theory include everything that we consider bad for all the obvious reasons: killing, stealing, cheating, what have you. But it seems in practice to have a narrower meaning, focussing on acts which are breaches of a religious code. Sex outside of marriage is considered immoral only because there's a rule against it. Even killing is considered "immoral" because it's in the Ten Commandments.

On the other hand, eating bacon on Yom Kippur is a flagrant breach of religious regulations, but I don't think you would use the word "immoral" to describe it. It's definitely not "unethical".

So I guess in the end I just don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Neither is a native German word, but Latin. The best thing to do would be to consult a German specialty dictionary dealing with philosophical terms. *Die Moral* in German is usually translated as 'morality', but not always. It must not be assumed that the English words 'morality' and 'ethics' correspond in all details.

Comment: "Ethics" comes from Greek ΗΘΙΚΗ. The Greeks made notable contributions to the discipline. For instance Aristotle's ΗΘΙΚΑ ΝΙΚΟΜΑΧΕΙΑ